# CURL on Unix or Linux reports as binary file & shows control characters as opposed to what response header says and no issues on Windows

Tags: json, linux, unix

When consuming JSON from an API into our NodeJS application using CURL on Linux slave (MacOS), we see binary file with control characters between every character although response header shows correct content-type (application/json; charset=utf-16)

Attempting to remove control characters (json.parse) results in malformed JSON.

Text editor on Windows (notepad, notepad++) don't show control characters as they convert the file encoding

Using 'body-parser' also does not seem to work

CURL command:

```
curl -D header.txt -o output.json -XGET "API call that returns JSON output"
```

The below code replaces control characters only if requesting less product count from the API:

```
    if (_.isString(response)) {
          var responseString = response
          .replace(/[\u0000-\u001F]+/g, '');
}
```

The API consumed by non unix/linux users are not having any issues.

If the fix should be at the API level, please let us know what should be the fix?

If the fix should be at the consuming end, please let us know what should be the fix?

Comment: There are no control characters, that's just the UTF-16 encoding. You need to make sure you read it as UTF-16 and not as ASCII or UTF-8 which is what basically all tools default to.

Comment: It didn't make much difference as the response headers are different to the actual response which shows as binary file instead of txt or json file.

Answer (score 0):

To fix on API level,

Do this, as you using nodejs application

```
res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json; charset=utf-8')
```

Please mind the encoding `utf-8`

To fix on consumer level

Do this, (if nodejs application, considering `response` is an instance of `Buffer`)

`const readableResponse = response.toString('utf-8')`